# Publish two-layer application on azure and create a subdomain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, subdomain

I have two-layer application my front end is written NuxtJS and my back end is written in .NET core.
I would like to publish this in azure. Should I be interested in azure static application or app services?
I would also like to create a subdomain where I can have a separate administration panel.

I would like to get this result:

```
exampledomain.com - Shop
admin.exampledomain.com - Admin panel
```

Can someone guide me how to publish such an application and how to create such a subdoemene in azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with Azure App Service, and publish multiple Web Apps inside the same Application Service Plan, but they will share the same compute resources.

To setup a custom domain, you just need to choose a plan that supports it and follow the following official doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?tabs=cname